# Dynamic snitches in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

What is significance of the following parameters in the cassandra.yaml file, keeping in view the various types of snitches we have.

```
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
```

Do these parameters still hold a meaningful significance in the newer Cassandra versions?

thanks
bhupen

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic snitch is not a type of snitch, but a wrapper that wraps the snitch of choice you determine. It gives snitches the ability to monitor read latency and helps the coordinator determine the best possible node to read from. More information on how this snitch works can be found [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/dynamic-snitching-in-cassandra-past-present-and-future).

As for the parameters, there is a short description on each parameter in the [cassandra.yaml file](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml):

```
# controls how often to perform the more expensive part of host score
# calculation
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 

# controls how often to reset all host scores, allowing a bad host to
# possibly recover
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000

# if set greater than zero, this will allow
# 'pinning' of replicas to hosts in order to increase cache capacity.
# The badness threshold will control how much worse the pinned host has to be
# before the dynamic snitch will prefer other replicas over it.  This is
# expressed as a double which represents a percentage.  Thus, a value of
# 0.2 means Cassandra would continue to prefer the static snitch values
# until the pinned host was 20% worse than the fastest.
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1
```

Comment: Thanks! So dynamic snitch is an add on feature on top of the actual snitch I choose for the node/cluster. In my case, I have chosen "simpleSnitch" and enabled the dynamic snitch parameters (by default basically) but when "nodetool describecluster" shows snitch type "DynamicSnitch" !!! why so?

Comment: Good catch. This is actually an odd behavior that has been fixed in later versions of Cassandra (3.11.2 and 4.0) The problem was that it only shows the wrapping class there which was not very helpful or user friendly. You can find the ticket on this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13528